# Animation trigged in any Iphone browser when its not supposed to be

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone

I have an animation that is trigged when user clicks in any "a" ellemnt that matches certain conditions. This animation is not suppose to work when the browser back button is clicked, but for some weird reason, in every iPhone its being trigged by that browser back button.
Is there a way to add an exception for that?

```
$("a").not('a[target="_blank"],a[href*="#"],a[href="/"]').click(function(evt){
    var URL = $(this).attr("href");
        setTimeout( function() { window.location = URL }, 900 );
      $(".next-animation").addClass("animation-on");

});
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to determine if the user's mobile is iPhone something like this

```
function isiPhone(){
    return (
        (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPhone") != -1) ||
        (navigator.platform.indexOf("iPod") != -1)
    );
}

if(!isiPhone()){
   $("a").not('a[target="_blank"],a[href*="#"],a[href="/"]').click(function(evt){
       var URL = $(this).attr("href");
       setTimeout( function() { window.location = URL }, 900 );
       $(".next-animation").addClass("animation-on");
   });
}
```

Then wrap your logic on this condition so it will not work if the user's phone is Apple Device

Comment: Actually, I dont want that animation to work when iphone browser's back button is pressed.

Comment: I don't think, we can detect that if the user is pressing the back button or forward. I suppose you need to change the logic of your code. Add a ".class" and on only if that class is clicked trigger the event.

Comment: I see, your solution worked fine on chrome, but not safari. Quite a strange problem.